# How to automatically load from folder and convert XML to MIR and put it into another folder?

Tags: xml, mir

How to automatically load from folder and convert XML to MIR and put it into another folder? The code needs to do this automatically in Windows.

I am starting this now. I am open to any suggestion. I haven't started it yes, because I have not found anything on MIR file format.

Comment: You could probably achieve it via XSLT.

Comment: I found the MIR specification (https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml) which in introduction links to YAML.  I think best approach is to use Powershell which can easily parse an XML file.  I also found a Powershell cmdlet which exports to YAML (https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml)